# Cydia WiFi Hotspot for SSH Without SIM Card

Tags: wifi, iphone, jailbreak, ssh, tweaks

I have recently jailbroken an old iPhone 4 I have and have been having a great experience with it as a device to fiddle with, however I need to be able to use it in areas where there isn't any WiFi over SSH.

Is there any tweak installable which will allow me to toggle the phone to make a WiFi Hotspot. The phone will not have a SIM Card installed to I don't care about mobile data. I simply want to connect to the phone's WiFi hotspot and SSH into its console via my iPad.

Thanks for any responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution which DOES involve a SIM card to this issue, but without the recurring fee of a SIM card. I purchased an EE SIM card for 99p at a local shop and stuffed it into the phone. On that SIM card I did get some free texts, minutes and data, but I used all the data up quickly and the minutes and texts had their free period expire. Now, this SIM was a pay-as-you-go SIM, and was not linked in any way to any of my payment details, meaning I can use it in data mode without any further cost. Simply, I turned on Mobile Data even though I had no data left and had not topped the card up with enough money to buy a data pack, and this allowed me to turn on Personal Hotspot. If I connect to this phone with another iDevice, I get captive.apple.com sign-in pop up, which can be disabled by tapping cancel, pressing the blue i next to the hostspot network under WiFi and switching off Auto-Login. Connecting again will make the hotspot stay connected and any attempt to connect to the internet from a tethered iDevice will result in being redirected to the Buy More Data popup.

Connecting via USB to a Windows PC also resulted in this popup, but simply closing it fixed it.

I can now find the IP address of the currently tethered device, for example 172.11.34.4 and work out that the hotspot's IP address is 172.11.34.1 which, connecting in an SSH app brings me to the OpenSSH command prompt! Hurray!

This was with an EE SIM, and if you are in America or elsewhere I believe EE isn't an option for you, but just because it worked with an EE SIM doesn't mean it won't also work with another kind of pay-as-you-go pick up at the store SIM.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a package that will let you SSH from a hotspot coming from the phone, but I think you would have an easier time starting a hotspot on your iPad connecting the phone to the hotspot & SSHing from there.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I can only start a hotspot on a 3G enabled iPad, which I do not have. My iPad isn't jail broken, as it is brand new, and the whole point of the phone was to be an old, jail broken device. Am I missing something on the iPad?

Comment: Ah I didn't realize this. This should be possible but it's such a niche use case (creating a wifi network not connected to the Internet for the purpose of SSHing) that I'm not sure that you'll find an application that does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A tweak named Polus allows changing Control Center toggle switches and has a switch for hotspot. Though you might be on a too low iOS version and not have a CC. In that case try SBSettings(iOS 6 and lower), but you will have to search and install desired toggles manually.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with a toggle, and i'm not willing to spend money on something not certain to work. Thanks for suggesting anyway :D